# How to style the UL list to a single line

Tags: css

I want to render this list in a single line.

- List item1
- List item2

Should be shown as

*List item2 *List item2

What CSS style to use?

Comment: I know this question is not specific to bootstrap but I found bootstrap [thumbnails](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#thumbnails) to be very useful for horizontal list of text, images, video etc.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

```
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

For more see the [basic list options](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/)  and [a basic horizontal list](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal01.htm) at listamatic.  (thanks to [Daniel Straight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65393/daniel-straight) below for the links).

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you probably want styling on the ul and whatever elements go inside the li's and the li's themselves to get things to look nice.

Comment: While this gets the job done, you will also want to include some padding to keep the elements spaced nicely

Comment: correct, this just makes the list horizontal. you probably want to add quite a bit more styling to the ul, li and whatever goes in the li to make things look nice.

Comment: How to get the bullets to stay? Or can we bullets by some other way.

Comment: as @DotDot points out: using {display: inline} removes the bullet styling. Get around this is: 1. use {float: left} instead (not working on IE9 though). 2. add a left-padding & add a background image (that is the bullet as a background image).

Answer (score 34):

In modern browsers you can do the following (CSS3 compliant)

```css
ul
{
  display:flex;  
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 17):

HTML code:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
ul.list li{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Try experimenting with something like this also:

> HTML

```
 <ul class="inlineList">
   <li>She</li>
   <li>Needs</li>
   <li>More Padding, Captain!</li>
 </ul>
```

> CSS

```
 .inlineList {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   /* Below sets up your display method: flex-start|flex-end|space-between|space-around */
   justify-content: flex-start; 
   /* Below removes bullets and cleans white-space */
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   /* Bonus: forces no word-wrap */
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
 /* Here, I got you started.
 li {
   padding-top: 50px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   padding-left: 50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
 }
 */
```

I made a codepen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/agm1984/pen/mOxaEM

Answer (score 3):

in **bootstrap** use `.list-inline` css class

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_txt_list-inline&stacked=h

Comment: And if you are using Bootstrap v4, `<li class="list-inline-item">bla bla</li>`

Answer (score 3):

Method 1:
Using Float Concept:

```css
ul li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Method 2: Using display inline property

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Method 3:
Using display inline-block properties

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Method 4:
Using Flex Properties - Modern One

```css
ul {
display: flex;
list-style: none;
gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Method 5: Using Grid Properties - Modern One

```css
ul {
display: grid;
list-style: none;
grid-auto-flow: column;
gap: 15px;
grid-auto-columns: max-content;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Method 6: Using Table Method - Old Method One

```css
ul {
display: table;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

list with a single line with a dot

[image]