# UL not staying in one single line

Tags: html, css, html-lists, horizontallist

I tried what this said: [How to style the UL list to a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976897/how-to-style-the-ul-list-to-a-single-line)

```
display: inline;
```

and didn't work!

[image]

**----------- My Code -----------**

**CSS:**

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

ul{
list-style:none;
}

#bottom_header{
background:#0F1923;
border-bottom:5px solid #0F67A1;
font-size:.95em;
font-weight:700;
height:31px;
padding:0 0 0 10px;
/*min-width:800px;*/
}

#bottom_header ul li{
font-size:.95em;
margin:0 0 0 6px;
padding:8px;
float:left;
display:inline;
}

#bottom_header ul li.active{
background:transparent url(./tab_left.png) no-repeat top left;
font-size:1.05em;
margin:-4px 0 auto 5px;
padding:0;
position:relative;
}

#bottom_header ul li.active a{
background:transparent url(./tab_right.png) no-repeat top right;
display:block;
margin:0 0 0 6px;
padding:10px 15px 10px 10px;
}

#bottom_header ul li.active,#bottom_header ul li.active a,#bottom_header ul li a:hover{
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}

#bottom_header ul li,#bottom_header ul li a{
color:#aeaeae;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bottom_header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="left active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just `float` all the `li`s the to the left.

Actually, you are doing that.

Just set a `width` on the `<div id="bottom_header">` so that it doesn't wrap.

For example:

```
#bottom_header{
    background:#0F1923;
    border-bottom:5px solid #0F67A1;
    font-size:.95em;
    font-weight:700;
    height:31px;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    width:800px;  /* ADD A WIDTH */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CtkrZ/

**EDIT**

As per your comment below:

> edit: I set 100% width and didn't fix that (also it created an
>   annoying horizontal line at all times on the whole page)

Remove the `width` from the `div` and add it to the `ul`.  Give the `ul` an `overflow:hidden;` too.

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:500px;   
}

#bottom_header{
    background:#0F1923;
    border-bottom:5px solid #0F67A1;
    font-size:.95em;
    font-weight:700;
    height:31px;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Updated Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CtkrZ/1/

Comment: edit: I set 100% width and didn't fix that (also it created an annoying horizontal line at all times on the whole page)

Answer (score -1):

```
ul > li{
   float: left;
}
```

OR

```
ul > li{
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This answer is not really useful if the user already states that `display: inline` doesn't work. The real problem is that the elements simply don't fit all horizontally, and therefore it renders all elements that don't fit below.