# How to avoid breaking <li>'s in an inline <ul>?

Tags: html, css

I have an inline ul, like so:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>...</span></li>
  <li><span>...</span></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

with `ul { list-style-type: none; }` and `li { display: inline }`. Each item is a tag, and the final product looks extremely similar to StackOverflow's list of tags on each question (a `<li>` contains some text and an icon).

My problem is that when I have enough items to reach the end of the line, the last `<li>` breaks, leaving half on the current line and the other half on the next line.

How to avoid this?

To elaborate (I am using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)]):

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="user_tag">User 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></li>
    <li><span class="user_tag">User 2 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

(note that Bootstrap fills the `span.glyphicon` with the appropriate icon). As to the styling (using SASS syntax):

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;

  .user_tag {
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}
```

The problem is that upon reaching the right edge of the `<div>`, the last user is broken, leaving his name on the current line, and the glyphicon on the next line.

Comment: Can you post more of your html and css?

Comment: What are the spans for?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976897/how-to-style-the-ul-list-to-a-single-line). Maybe that's what you are looking for? Something like `ul li{ display: inline; }`?

Comment: The span basically contains text and an icon: ``<span>User Name <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>`` (the glyphicon is give by Bootstrap).

Comment: The ``li { display: inline }`` gives the inline list well. However, if, for example, the element ``<li>User 8...</li>`` fits partially on a line (e.g. if only ``User`` fits but not the number or the icon), then it is broken, with ``User`` appearing on the original line, but the rest appearing on the next line. The breaking is more obvious if we paint a border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact what you need is to change your `<ul>` element to

```
ul{display:block}
```

and `<li>` to

```
li{display:inline-block}
```

the nowrap approach will make that if you add a really long name, you'll end with a massive width `<li>` element. Unless you're looking for that, your approach is incorrect, might work in this specific case, but it's a NO-NO in general . I mean, it might apply to your case and ONLY TO YOUR CASE, but for people seeing this thread, it's better not to follow that path since it's incorrect

Answer (score 9):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap` to your `li` style. That should prevent it from breaking mid-word and will wrap the entire thing to the next line.

Comment: @Gonzalo if you need to use such properties than am sure you are doing something wrong

Comment: Would you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: @Gonzalo I don't see any reason for preventing the text to wrap, It may also resukt in an overflow... p.s this answer is correct but your approach isn't

Comment: I have expanded my explanation of what I'm trying to achieve in the question above. Considering that, would you post an answer with a sketch of a better approach? Thanks!

Comment: @Gonzalo am on phone, but I read that you have too many items in a line and hence it breaks, so there is a flaw in your design. Group common functions and mockup the layout accordingly