# list items horizontally rather than vertical using <ul><li> tags

Tags: css

I have this web page

http://hashgurus.com/htmlpage7.html  which lists items in

```
<li>    </li>
```

vertically. But I need it to display horizontally. Which element in css should I use to display items horizontally rather than vertically?

this is the code:

```
<ul class="jobs">
        <li>
            <img height="80px" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEQnmWnWgAArgtf.jpg" />

                <div class="company">desc1</div></li>

        <li>
            <img height="80px" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEQnmWnWgAArgtf.jpg" />

                <div class="company">desc2</div></li>
    </ul>
```

demo page:
    http://hashgurus.com/htmlpage7.html

Comment: You can float the list items left or change their display to inline or inline block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style the UL list to a single line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976897/how-to-style-the-ul-list-to-a-single-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.jobs {
list-style-type: none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.jobs > li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Something like that perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your list elements align horizontally by specifying the display property with `inline`.

An example of this below:

```css
li{display:inline}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: first thing you have not closed `ul` tag and second the `inline` elements gives extra whitespace between them http://jsfiddle.net/vg1f4nku/ so it will not work if OP gives `width:50%`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

for floating the list elements to the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use float but you need to clear after it or will have layout problems.

Example :

```css
.jobs {
  list-style: none;
}

.jobs li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.jobs::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="jobs">
  <li>
    <img height="80px" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEQnmWnWgAArgtf.jpg" />

    <div class="company">desc1</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <img height="80px" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEQnmWnWgAArgtf.jpg" />

    <div class="company">desc2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use floats for layout unless absolutely necessary. They are horribly buggy. Floats **should** be used for removing an element from the "normal" document flow while allowing content to flow around the element. A good example would be an image in a paragraph.

Instead set the `font size: 0` on the container to remove unwanted white space between items, and `white-space: nowrap` to keep them inline when the container is bigger than the window. Reset the font and white-space in the child and set to `display: inline-block`.

Using inline-block instead of inline allows you to change the width and height of each element.

**Note** if you set the font for `html` to reference that font-size later you can use `rem` units which refer to the font size of the root element. In this example I use `1rem` to reset the font size to that of the root element.

```
ul {
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    white-space: initial;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img height="80px" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEQnmWnWgAArgtf.jpg" />
      <div class="company">desc1</div></li>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img height="80px" src="http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CEQnmWnWgAArgtf.jpg" />
      <div class="company">desc2</div></li>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```